# Why Spark - countByValue () is causing FileNotFoundException?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark, Installed Spark in my windows machine and executing spark command in spark-shell . Created simple `RDD` and find no. of times text occurs. here is my block of code. it is causing `FileNotFound Exception`.

```
scala>  val inputrdd = sc.parallelize{ Seq("a", "b", "c", "d","a","a") }
inputrdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[70] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala>  inputrdd.count
res102: Long = 6

scala>  inputrdd.first
res103: String = a

scala>

scala>  inputrdd.countByValue()
2018-09-26 19:32:03 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 5.0 in stage 72.0 (TID 113)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\hadoop\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-910b1c57-9f3a-4dea-a80b-701ad0a32ead\1f\shuffle_6_5_0.data.6bac0b0d-93a6-4b57-a1d6-8dbe379c264f (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedPairCollection$$anon$1.writeNext(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.writePartitionedFile(ExternalSorter.scala:699)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rerun the same code from scratch and it will work without any problem.

Reason: `C:\Users\hadoop\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-910b1c57-9f3a-4dea-a80b-701ad0a32ead` got deleted somehow. It stores temporary data which a dataframe holds at runtime and that was lost.

Comment: After removing also getting the same exception

Comment: No you need it. Don't remove it. Just execute complete code again and print exception if it occurred again. Also if exception still persists then we need to check who is deleting that directory.